# Trigger the collapsible in JQUERY Mobile with a seperate button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible in JQUERY Mobile that i im using as a read more. when the collapsible gets expanded  there is a fixed button and the bottom of the screen that says close to make it so you dont have to scroll back to the top to close the collapsible.

What i want to do is trigger the collapsible to close with the fixed close button on the bottom of the screen. i have tried bind methods but my inexperience is hindering my understanding.

here is the code im using.

```
<div id="showbutton" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-transition="turn" data-content-theme="d" class="ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">
    <h2>Read more</h2>
    <h2 id="content">Lots and lots of content here</h2>

        <footer align="center" id="closefooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $("#closebutton").click(function() {
                        console.log("ok");
                    $( "#showbutton" ).trigger( "closebutton" );
                    });
                 });
            </script> 
        <a id="closebutton">close</a>
    </footer>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nmxav27t/

```
$(document).on("click", "#closebutton", function(event) {
    $("#showbutton").collapsible("collapse");
});
```

You need to bind a click (or tap event) on the button you want to use for closing, then trigger collapse on the **showbutton** id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collapse() method as described here: https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/

```
$( ".selector" ).collapsible( "collapse" );
```

Comment: I have tried this but the problem is mostly my lack of understanding of how this works. Will you please give me an example.    I used (#showbutton) as the selector but i cant get it to trigger the collapsible. Is it a container problem or a syntax problem?